# uninitialized constant RspecApiDocumentation using apitome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-api-documentation, apitome

When following the [instructions](https://github.com/jejacks0n/apitome) for setting up aptitome with rspec_api_documentation, I receive the following error:

```
uninitialized constant RspecApiDocumentation
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by removing the configuration from `spec_helper.rb` and setting up an initializer as per this [blog](https://blog.codeship.com/producing-documentation-for-your-rails-api/), i.e.

```
# config/initializers/rspec_api_documentation.rb
RspecApiDocumentation.configure do |config|
  # Output folder
  config.docs_dir = Rails.root.join("doc", "api")

  # An array of output format(s).
  # Possible values are :json, :html, :combined_text, :combined_json,
  #   :json_iodocs, :textile, :markdown, :append_json
  config.format = [:json]
end
```